# Editing MS Word header with win32com

Tags: python, ms-word, win32com

I'm trying to edit header of a MS Word document that has existing header using `win32com`.
I tried this to edit page header:

```
import win32com.client as win32

word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
doc=word.Documents.Open("C:\\a.docx")
word.Visible = True
word.ActiveDocument.Sections[0].Headers[win32.constants.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.Text='test text'
word.ActiveDocument.Save()
doc.Close(False)
word.Application.Quit()
```

But it has no effect (header didn't changed at all)!!
What is the correct way to edit MS Word header via win32com ?

Comment: Brave soul... Have you considered the indexes? At least in macros and C# they are 1-based, not 0-based. You should be able to get a header by integer index as well.  I've only dealt with Word through C# and VB so I'm not sure this is relevant

Comment: I think Sten Petrov may be right. It's been a while since I used `win32com`, but in general neither it nor VB does anything clever with indices; the VB interface is 1-based because the underlying `IDispatch` interface is, and therefore so is the `win32com` interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use parentheses instead of square brackets in this line, along with 1-based indexing.  Everything in COM is a function call or property.

```
word.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(win32.constants.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text='test text'
```