# Reading Table Contet In Header And Footer In MS-Word File Using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ms-word, pywin32, win32com

This is my extended question  for the question:

[How to read contents of an Table in MS-Word file Using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366596/reading-table-contetnts-in-ms-word-file-using-python)

The solution provided by @YusuMishi is great, but it does not catch the headers in the header and footer.

Let me elaborate on that:
[image]

Using the code

```
import win32com.client as win32
import os
word = win32.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.Visible = 0
p = os.path.abspath("Catch my tables.docx")
word.Documents.Open(p)
doc = word.ActiveDocument
print doc.Tables.Count
```

I will get `2` printed (`Table 1` and `Table 2`)

How do I go through the information in `Table 0` and `Table N`

[Get the document here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-Kgtt1jTEbfYVhaQU9kN0tJbHc/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing Headers and Footers is a bit tricky. Here is how to do it:

```
HeaderTable = doc.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.Tables(1)
FooterTable = doc.Sections(1).Footers(1).Range.Tables(1)
```

You can get the table count this way:

```
HeaderTablesCount = doc.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.Tables.Count
FooterTablesCount = doc.Sections(1).Footers(1).Range.Tables.Count
```

And get the text from cells this way:

```
HeaderTable.Cell(1,1).Range.Text
FooterTable.Cell(1,1).Range.Text
```

Comment: BTW: what is the best way to cut of the u' and \r\x07 ?

Comment: Check my answer to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423593/unwanted-character-in-excel-cell-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I'm not [phyton](/questions/tagged/phyton) programmer but have some knowledge of MS-Word VBA and objects hierarchy. This would be to much text to put in comment (where I'd rather put this tip).

If you search your table you have to analyse different `Document.StoryRanges` to find your table. There are `Footers` and `Headers` but they are additionally divided into different types. So, to find you Table 0 you could use something of this structure:

`This is VBA code!! I hope you could adjust to your needs. And do it separately for you footers.`

```
doc.StoryRanges(wdEvenPagesHeaderStory).Tables.Count
doc.StoryRanges(wdFirstPageHeaderStory).Tables.Count
doc.StoryRanges(wdPrimaryHeaderStory).Tables.Count
```